# Possible to predict the shape of a waveform given another waveform?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

Here I have two waveforms that may possibly be correlated:

[image: Both waveforms]

Do you think it would be possible to train an algorithm to predict one waveform given another?

I'm fairly new to ML but I was thinking of trying gradient descent with something like this:

[image]

Where I would parse through the signal at every point, maybe with some x(t-1), x(t-2) terms thrown in.

But I've never attempted anything like this before so I'm not sure if it would work. How computationally intensive would it even be to try and minimize a least squares cost function with this many parameters?

Answer (score 0):

As a first step I would suggest a [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) to identify the principal frequencies. Then one can in real space use those frequencies as starting values for regression. Failure to do that would require global regression, because multiples and fractions of the principal frequencies will also yield solutions, but local ones that are not global.